# Who can move faster than max move speed?

Tags: dota-2

In DOTA2, 522 is considered the movespeed cap. Most abilities that grant maximum movespeed increase your movespeed to 522. There are also cumulative effects that when applied together will increase your speed to no greater than 522.

I'm wondering which heroes can run at faster than 522 movespeed, and what is required for them to do so?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Heroes who can benefit from a move speed superior than 522 :

- Bloodseeker with his thirst passive. Nothing is required except many
  enemies heros with low health. Technically he can reach speed beyond
  5000 with items that boost movespeed aswell.
- Lycan in Shapeshift form runs at 650ms.

Heroes with skills that induce a travel speed faster than 522ms. Though it's technically not increasing the hero's movespeed, those skill makes the hero move faster than the 522ms limit.

- Storm can break that limit with Ball Lightning. The ball moves at 1250/1875/2500 speed (depending on the level).
- Clockwerk's Hookshot travels at 4000/5000/6000 speed (depending on the level)
- Huskar's Lifebreak travels at 1000ms
- When Wisp Tethers to a far unit he can break the 522ms (1000ms)
- Magnus' Skewer travels at 950ms
- Timbersaw's Timberchain travels at 1600/2000/2400/2800 (depending on the level)
- Mirana's Leap reaches 1600ms
- Morphling's Waveform reaches 1250ms
- Void's Timewalk reaches 3000ms
- Slark Pounces at 933,33ms
- Ember Spirit joins a Fire Remnant at 1300ms
- Phoenix's Dive seems to break that 522ms barrier though the travel speed is not precised
- Earth Spirit's Rolling Boulder can reach 1600ms (800ms if it doesn't hit a Remnant)

Comment: Earth Spirit's Rolling Boulder can do 1600ms with remnants or 800ms without.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe at the engine level "Blink" skill will give the fastest movement. Anti-Mage, Blink at lvl 4 has 1150 range, casts for ~0.5sec (it's 0.4 actually) so the theoretical speed is 828000 units per hour :D

Answer (score 0):

In actual fact, ember spirit moves to his fire remnant instantly, although it does display him moving at extreme speed, prob past 5000ms.